# Material Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, scrollbar, custom-view, materialdrawer

I have created a navigation drawer using [Mike Penz's navigation drawer library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) which is as follows:[image] but m facing an issue that my view is not scrollable like other items infact other items are getting overlapped on my view while scrolling Its behaving like a sticky header.[image]Please find the images to understand my problem and give suggestions if any.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is better you should report this issue on GitHub. We don't know much about it! Good luck

Comment: Post the code, with the screenshots only we cant help

Comment: How do your items you add int he drawer look like? Remember that the scrolling container is a `RecyclerView` you may not want to add scrollviews as childs. What else did you change. the margins and paddings and the transparent bar on top do not look like in my library.

Comment: The issue is resolved now the items in holder was not getting recycled. Thanks.

Comment: Please answer your own question as soon as you can :) So other take advantage of your experience